# Question About Retain Counts & initializing member variables

Tags: objective-c

Imagine I have a member variable

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *array;
```

Now in my viewDidLoad I set up a simple array

```
array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B","C",nil];
```

My retain count for array is going to be 1 right?

Now if I were to set up the array using the accessor method

```
self.array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B","C",nil];
```

Is my retain count 2 because my accessor method bumps the retain count up by 1?

What's the convention for initializing member variables?

Comment: That's a property, not a member variable. They're two very different things.

Comment: Note also that Objective-C does not have member variables.  It has instance variables instead.  (More or less the same, but using the right terminology is helpful.)

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, the retain count for `self.array =` ends up as 2.

First, you `alloc init` a new `NSArray` object. That's a retain count of 1. Second, your setter sends the object a `retain` message when assigning it to your instance var. That bumps the retain count up to 2.

> What's the convention for initializing member variables?

Besides directly setting the ivar `array =` as in your question, here are some ways to do this with your `self.array` property without leaking:

1. Autorelease:

   ```
   self.array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil] autorelease];
   ```
2. Use the `arrayWithObjects:` class method. Simpler, and also produces an autoreleased object:

   ```
   self.array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
   ```
3. Make a temporary variable to hold the new pointer, then release it after setting the property (which will have had it retained by then):

   ```
   NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
   self.array = tmpArray;
   [tmpArray release];
   ```

Comment: What about using the first option array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:....]; It seems the simplest why don't you suggest that one?