# Why retainCount returns 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myvar;
```

First case:

```
    myvar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@retainCount: %i:", [myvar  retainCount]);
```

outputs:

> retainCount: 1

Second case:

```
    self.myvar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@retainCount: %i:", [self.myvar  retainCount]);
```

outputs:

> retainCount: 2

My question is: why in the second case retain value is 2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why retain count in negative value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601270/why-retain-count-in-negative-value) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418230/why-is-the-retain-count-of-1-equal-to-7-8-or-10), and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883616/ios-reference-counting), and [this one as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043994/ios-memory-management-clarifications).

Comment: There are many questions here about why not to use retain count for your memory management. Here's a a link that explains it too. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 because you `alloc/init`'d it
+1 because `self.myvar` retains it (as set out in your property declaration)

if you `autorelease` after alloc/init, it will go back down to 1... then if you set `self.myvar` to nil, it will hit 0 (if nothing else has retained it in the meantime)

But as vikingosegundo has said, you don't want to be messing with retain counts. The OS determines when to knock them back down, so you can't use them as a reliable measure of state.

Comment: i didn't notice that self.myvar is something completely diffrent than myvar. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The only valid answer: never check, use, trust retainCount. it is not meant for debugging or use directly for memory management.

useful: [whentouseretaincount.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130202210240/http://www.whentouseretaincount.com/)

But in your case: As you are not using ARC (otherwise the compile wouldnt allow you to use `retainCount` anyway) you are over retaining.

it retain here `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myvar;`

and here: `self.myvar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

do:

```
self.myvar = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; //will release once soon
```

or <sub>my favorite, as independent from ARC/MRC and short</sub>

```
self.myvar = [NSMutableArray array]; // identical to the first example
```

or more explicit

```
NSMutableArray *var = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
self.myvar = var; 
[var release];
```

Comment: @H2CO3, you are right.

Comment: I always used convenient methods.

Comment: Yes, those are better for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rule that I used to go by before ARC came along:

'The NARC rule':

If you use `New`, `Alloc`, `Retain` or `Copy`, increase the count by one.

Your retain count is 2 in the second case because you are using `alloc` and `retain` on the instance property of the class (by using the `self` keyword). In the other case you are not using the synthesized setter to set the variable, and therefore not using `retain`. Explore what properties actually do for increased understanding.

vikingosegundo has explained well the correct way to do things in his answer.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Question About Retain Counts & initializing member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972430/question-about-retain-counts-initializing-member-variables)

> First, you alloc init a new NSArray object. That's a retain count of
>   1.  Second, your setter sends the object a retain message when assigning it to your instance var. That bumps the retain count up to
>   2.

Cheers.